# Replacing all occurrences of a String with RegEx keys from a Map

Tags: java, regex, hashmap, java-8

I have String like below,

> {Account={type=object,id={type=integer, format=int64}, enum=[ENABLED, DISABLED]}, token={type=string}}}, AssetPlayerRequest={type=object, properties={assetPlayer={description=The asset player details, {$ref=#/definitions/AssetPlayer},ImageFile={type=object, properties={description={type=string}, filePath={type=string}, fileUri={$ref=#/definitions/URI}}}

I want to replace the RegEx patterns like `{$ref=#/definitions/URI}`, `{$ref=#/definitions/AssetPlayer}` with the values available in a Map with Keys like `URI`, `AssetPlayer` which are part of RegEx itself.

How to achieve this in Java 8?

Answer (score 3):

Partially adapted from  `Matcher.replaceAll()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> replacements = new HashMap<>();
    replacements.put("AssetPlayer", "replacement1");
    replacements.put("URI", "replacement2");
    
    String input = "{Account={type=object,id={type=integer, format=int64}, enum=[ENABLED, DISABLED]}, token={type=string}}}, AssetPlayerRequest={type=object, properties={assetPlayer={description=The asset player details, {$ref=#/definitions/AssetPlayer},ImageFile={type=object, properties={description={type=string}, filePath={type=string}, fileUri={$ref=#/definitions/URI}}}";
    
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\{\\$ref=#\\/definitions\\/(.+?)\\}").matcher(input);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    if (matcher.find()) {
        do {
            String replacement = replacements.get(matcher.group(1));
            matcher.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement));
        } while (matcher.find());
        matcher.appendTail(sb);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    } else {
        System.out.println(input);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{Account={type=object,id={type=integer, format=int64}, enum=[ENABLED, DISABLED]}, token={type=string}}}, AssetPlayerRequest={type=object, properties={assetPlayer={description=The asset player details, replacement1,ImageFile={type=object, properties={description={type=string}, filePath={type=string}, fileUri=replacement2}}
```

Since Java 9, you can simplify this with the new functional [`Matcher.replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-):

```
String result = Pattern.compile("\\{\\$ref=#\\/definitions\\/(.+?)\\}")
        .matcher(input)
        .replaceAll(match -> Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacements.get(match.group(1))));
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Note that `/` has no special meaning in Java regex, hence, doesn’t need escaping. And you can pull the `StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();` line inside the `if` statement, as it isn’t needed, when there is no match. Java 9 is going to allow `StringBuilder` here. At last…

Answer (score 1):

The general formula for replacing things in a string that requires more logic is in [`Matcher#appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-):

```
public String bindTemplateVariables(String input) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{\\$ref=#/definitions/(.*?)\\}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        String replacement = map.get(m.group(1));
        m.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```